# Generating Java Classes

Tags: clojure

I understand that one can use `gen-class` to generate a java class, however, I'm confused as to how I can generate a java class *with* constructors. Is it possible to generate a java class with a constructor, that does not extend or implement another class?

Answer (score 3):

I just generated following class with constructor:

```
(ns test.t1
  (:import (java.util HashMap))
  (:gen-class
   :main false
   :state state
   :init init
   :constructors {[java.util.HashMap] []}))
(defn -init [^HashMap tmapref]
  [[] tmapref])
```

and I able to create instance of it:

```
user> (test.t1. (java.util.HashMap.))
#<t1 test.t1@7d6ac92e>
```